# What is the difference between C++ 14 and C++ 5.1 in Ideone?

Tags: c++

I get to choose an option while I do competitive programming. I have tried both and most of the times I prefer C++ 14. Does choosing the other one make any difference in an answer or a compilation?

Comment: C++ 5.1 is probably some tool version, not language standard (like C++14). You can't compare tool version against standard version

Comment: Where did you see this? We may need to have someone correct it.

Comment: I'm actually upvoting this now because if you're using ideone.com this huge misunderstanding is not at all your fault.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, This is the first time i saw C++ 5.1 (in Ideone)

Comment: For future reference, it's a good idea to cite your sources in questions ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**C++14 is an international language standard**, formally entitled ISO/IEC 14882:2014(E). The nomenclature indicates that this is the version of the C++ language published by ISO in 2014.

**C++ 5.1 does not exist**. In the 1980s there were versions of pre-standard "C++" that Bjarne Stroustrup created for fun, variously called C++ 1.0 and C++ 2.0. However, this versioning system did not reach 5.1 by the time the language became standardised as ISO/IEC 14882:1998(E) in 1998.

It is possible that you are instead referring to the version number of some Integrated Development Environment (a piece of software for your computer, consisting of a text editor and wrapping a compiler/debugger). For example, you could be talking about version 5.1.0.0 of the IDE fork known as "Orwell Dev-C++", [which dates back to 2011](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/dev-c-5100-released.html).

On the other hand, if these are options presented to you as languages in some online tool, the tool is *wrong*. For example, [ideone.com](http://ideone.com) offers ["c++ 5.1" which is, apparently, GCC 5.1 in C++98 mode](https://goo.gl/W6iPtK).

Comment: Orwell Dev-C++ is now at v5.11. I suggest upgrading if this is indeed what you are talking about.

Comment: Another possibility might be g++ 5.1  . The online "compiler" [ideone](http://ideone.com/) offers "c++ 5.1".

Comment: @MattMcNabb That's crazy.  I sent them feedback with: `You are branding straight C++ as C++ 5.1 as it is using the gcc 5.1 compiler.  I think this is going to confuse people as there is no C++ 5.1.  I think it should be renamed to C++ gcc 5.1`

Comment: @NathanOliver: It would be better off saying "GCC 5.1 (C++03)". To be fair, the site also pluralises "code" in several places, so... ;)

Comment: [This post is being discussed on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300914/560648).

Comment: Anyone who pluralizes 'code' needs to be slapped in the face.

Comment: What if they're British and use "maths" too?

Comment: @CoryKramer: Then they are awesome. (*ahem* _"mathematicS"_)

Answer (score 2):

[C++14](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language) is a version of the C++ standard. The standard specifies the types, syntax, semantics, etc that all C++ compilers must (try to) adhere to.

[Dev-C++ 5.1](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.com/2012/02/dev-c-5110-released.html) is a version of an IDE, of which there are many others. It uses GCC under the hood as the compiler. Depending on the GCC version, it may support different iterations of the C++ standard, which will affect which library features are available.